# issues while searching models in wagtail django

Tags: python, django, search, wagtail, wagtail-search

I'm having a bit of crisis in searching models in wagtail django

This is my code for model objects

```
recipes = RecipePage.objects.child_of(self).live().public() \
        .select_related('listing_image')
    extra_url_params = ''
    error_message=False
    filter_categories_raw = request.GET.get('categories')
    filter_categories = False
    filter_name = request.GET.get("name")
    
    if filter_categories_raw:
        filter_categories = []
        filter_categories_raw = filter_categories_raw.split(",")
        for fc in filter_categories_raw:
            try:
                value = int(fc)
                filter_categories.append(value)
            except ValueError:
                filter_categories = False
                error_message = "Invalid category value"

    if filter_categories:
        for filter_category in filter_categories:
            recipes = recipes.filter(categories__category=filter_category)
    
    if filter_name:
        recipes = recipes.search(filter_name, recipes) <---- issue here
        
    if not filter_name:
        filter_name=""
```

My RecipePage model I added

```
search_fields = BasePage.search_fields + [
    index.SearchField('title'),
]
```

Now when I do this for searching,

```
recipes = recipes.search(filter_name, recipes)
```

it gives me error

> Can't convert 'RecipePage' object to str implicitly

When I do this

```
recipes = recipes.search(filter_name, recipes.title) or recipes = recipes.search(filter_name, recipes.objects)
```

It gives me

> 'PageQuerySet' object has no attribute 'title'

I'm stoned. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are you expecting the second parameter of `search` to do? Why not just `recipes.search(filter_name)`?

Answer (score 0):

When you look at the [docs for searching in Wagtail](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.0/topics/search/searching.html) you'll see there are two ways to search in Wagtail, that I think you are mixing up. The first is the most obvious, by simply passing a search term to the search method on a QuerySet. The second is by passing a search term and a QuerySet to the search_backend's search method.

In your case either:

Remove the QuerySet from your `search` call:

```
 recipes = recipes.search(filter_name)
```

or:

Pass the search term and QuerySet to the search_backend:

from wagtail.search.backends import get_search_backend

```
s = get_search_backend()
s.search(filter_name, recipes)
```

Comment: Hi, I did try this but there is a many-to-many relationship of categories in my RecipePage. You know, one recipe can have many categories etc. I cannot figure out how to add the FilterIndex of that relationship